# Creating scene mapping with a spreadsheet and referencing neighboring cells(scenes)

Tags: c#, excel, unity-game-engine

I'm unfortunately unsure on even what to google due to questionable terminology on this so please bear with me.
What I'm trying to accomplish for my Unity game that I'm working on is creating a master mapping scene spreadsheet. This scene spreadsheet would be referenced through the method, OnSceneLoaded.

My question is this through the following example. If the player is on scene 765 (as seen in the table below), I would like my method to reference the spreadsheet and parse in the values for the neighboring cardinal directions (indicated in red) into variables to be referenced based on the direction the player chooses to go by edge collider logic.

Id prefer to be able to do this through a spreadsheet rather than an array.

To summarize, if player is on scene 765, how do I syntactically say find 765 in my mapping spreadsheet and to reference the items in red (look up, down, left, right of number 765)?

[image: Table Example]

Comment: What's the data structure that you use to store the values?

Comment: The scenes aren't always numerically incremented when entered into the spreadsheet which is the kicker otherwise some other logic could be applied, i.e. scene 765 + 1, 765 -1....etc.

Comment: Why you do not convert it to table with scene_id and next_scene_id, where you place your 4 values? Then it will be very fast to read the hashmap by key and get available targets.

Comment: I'm not oppose to converting it to a table, but for ease of use (in my mind) I was thinking a spreadsheet could be easily updated...etc. @astentx My thought was to parse in the 4 possible scene #'s as the direction is not static in which the player may move. I'm not familiar with the process you mention in the latter half of your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As now I prefer PowerQuery over VBA for most data transformation tasks in excel, I can offer you to "parse" your gaming field to the structure I offered: 1 scene ID and 4 values of available scenes. This can give you a visual map and in the same time will keep things suitable for processing.
What to do:

1. Convert your field to R1C1-like format with PivotOtherColumns.
2. Select available fields by row and columns offset.
3. Load this data to new spreadsheet as scene_id and 4 column values of available next scenes.
4. Read this table to hashtable, where you'll have scene_id as a key and an array of 4 values as value.

Below is the code in PowerQuery:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
//Generate rownumbers
    AddIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Row", 0, 1),
//Generate column numbers
    Unpivot = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(AddIndex, {"Row"}, "Column", "Value"),
    RemoveColumnName = Table.ReplaceValue(Unpivot,"Column","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column"}),
//Convert column number to Int for offsetting
    ColnameToInt = Table.TransformColumnTypes(RemoveColumnName,{{"Column", Int64.Type}}),
    SelectVariants = Table.AddColumn(ColnameToInt, "AvailablePositions", (row) =>
//Create record from table
Record.FromTable(
//Change index column to text
  Table.TransformColumnTypes(
//Project only Name and Value columns to parse as record
    Table.SelectColumns(
//Add variant number to pivot it to column
      Table.AddIndexColumn(
//Select available scenes
        Table.SelectRows(ColnameToInt, each ( [Row] = row[Row] and Number.Abs([Column] - row[Column]) = 1) or ( [Column] = row[Column] and Number.Abs([Row] - row[Row]) = 1 ))
        , "Name", 0, 1
      ),
      {"Name", "Value"}
    ),
    {{"Name", type text}}
  )
)),
    ExpandVariants = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(SelectVariants, "AvailablePositions", {"0", "1", "2", "3"}, {"0", "1", "2", "3"}),
    FinalProjection = Table.RemoveColumns(ExpandVariants,{"Row", "Column"})
in
    FinalProjection
```

This is a source map (it is a Table named "Table1" for above code)

[image: Source]

This is a result

[image: Result]

If you need more scenes you just type new values in the next row or column and the table will be expanded by excel automatically. Then refresh powerquery and load to the program.

**EDIT**: Since you need an ordered columns, I've changed a code to make it done (columns NESW). If you need an offset by X and Y, just remove steps from "ExpandVariants" to bottom and get it in tabular format.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
//Generate rownumbers
    AddIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Row", 0, 1),
//Generate column numbers
    Unpivot = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(AddIndex, {"Row"}, "Column", "Value"),
    RemoveColumnName = Table.ReplaceValue(Unpivot,"Column","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column"}),
//Convert column number to Int for offsetting
    ColnameToInt = Table.TransformColumnTypes(RemoveColumnName,{{"Column", Int64.Type}}),
    SelectVariants = Table.AddColumn(ColnameToInt, "AvailablePositions", (row) =>
 Table.ExpandRecordColumn(
  Table.AddColumn(
   Table.SelectRows(ColnameToInt, each ( [Row] = row[Row] and Number.Abs([Column] - row[Column]) = 1) or ( [Column] = row[Column] and Number.Abs([Row] - row[Row]) = 1 )),
   "Direction",
   each [X = [Column] - row[Column], Y = [Row] - row[Row]]
  ),
  "Direction",
  {"X", "Y"}
 )
),
    ExpandVariants = Table.ExpandTableColumn(SelectVariants, "AvailablePositions", {"Value", "X", "Y"}, {"NextValue", "X", "Y"}),
    RenameVariants = Table.AddColumn(ExpandVariants, "VariantNames", each if [Y] = 1 and [X] = 0 then "N"
else if [Y] = 0 and [X] = 1 then "E"
else if [Y] = -1 and [X] = 0 then "S"
else if [Y] = 0 and [X] = -1 then "W"
else ""),
    SelectColumns = Table.SelectColumns(RenameVariants,{"Value", "NextValue", "VariantNames"}),
    PivotNESW = Table.Pivot(SelectColumns, List.Distinct(SelectColumns[VariantNames]), "VariantNames", "NextValue", (x)=>List.First(x) )
in
    PivotNESW
```

Result:
[image: Result_NESW]

Comment: So I got around to trying out your suggestion. After analyzing your example and applying to my current scene map, it seems as though the border scenes, when the powerquery code is applied to it, doesn't properly format to the correct column. More specific, say the letter "d" in your example which is surrounded in all directions parses out to column 0(north), 1(west), 2(east), 3(south) correctly. BUT a border scene such as "q" outputs it's neighboring scenes which are only east and south to the wrong columns. Is there additional logic that can be applied to address that?

Comment: @user1901231 I've updated the answer with appropriate code

Comment: Thank you very much for you help astentx!